# How do I complete the "Viatrix, The Annoying Pilgrim" quest?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-iii-morrowind

I'm trying to complete the "[Viatrix, The Annoying Pilgrim](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Morrowind:Viatrix,_The_Annoying_Pilgrim)" quest.

I can't find a way to get to the shrine. It seems the shrine is on a hill, although I can't confirm since I have to seen it other than in this map.

Accepted answer needs to have a map similar to mine, with a line drawn to what path I need to follow to get there.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you are looking in the wrong spot, the ruins you circled in blue in the question, is Odrosal and not related to this quest.

Try looking in the red circle below.

[image]

Comment: Don't try this quest early on. On my first attempt, I made it about 10 steps beyond Ghostgate before being immobilized and then killed by a rat.